# Путь к системным папкам

Tags: c#

Есть ли в C# методы похожие на Path.GetTempPath();? Что бы получать путь до таких папок как Program Files, Program Data.

Comment: [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @ГеннадийП, ответы - в ответы?

Comment: @Qwertiy Извиняюсь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть перечисление:

```
Environment.SpecialFolder
```

В нем перечислены основные папки, например: Windows, ProgramFiles, UserProfile. И есть метод, позволяющий передав элемент перечисления получить нужную папку:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows);
```

Answer (score 2):

Все находится в перечислении [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Следующий пример вернет путь к `C:\ProgramData`:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String programFiles = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
String programData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
```